# DataGridViewComboBoxColumn set the selectedindex

Tags: c#, winforms, gridview, datagridviewcombobox

hi i runtime bind the data into datagridview combobox. But how do i make it to auto display the first item? i do not able find the selectedindex from DataGridViewComboBoxColumn.

```
  DataGridViewComboBoxColumn cbStudentCourse = (DataGridViewComboBoxColumn)dgStudentCourse.Columns["studentCourseStatus"];
                    cbStudentCourse.DataSource = Enum.GetValues(typeof(CourseStudentStatus));
                    cbStudentCourse.DisplayIndex = 1;
```

-- Update ---
i saw someone doing this in solution 3
[LInk](http://www.codeproject.com/Answers/110537/Select-DataGridViewCombobox-cell-value-at-runtime.aspx#answer2)
Are you sure i need such a long code to just have the first item selected??????

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A **DataGridViewComboBoxColumn** has no `SelectedIndex`, and `SelectedValue` properties. However you can get the same behavior of `SelectedValue` by setting the **`Value`** property.

For instance on first index the value member has value 2 then you should set `.Value = "2"` to set the first index selected.

For example

```
myDataGridViewComboBoxColumn.Value = "20";
```

In your case

```
myDataGridViewComboBoxColumn.Value = CourseStudentStatus.EnumToBeSelected.ToString();
```

Here is more details about [DataGridViewComboBoxColumn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcomboboxcolumn.aspx)

Comment: i tried this  ` cbStudentCourse.ValueMember = CourseStudentStatus.Active.ToString();` but it still showing empty

Comment: 'ValueMember' is used for binding you need to set the 'Value' property

Comment: +1 accidentally i did; no property of value find. only valueMember and Valuetype Available

Comment: you can also check here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcomboboxcolumn.aspx

Answer (score 5):

the best way to set the value of a datagridViewComboBoxCell is:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("Item");
dt.Columns.Add("Value");
dt.Rows.Add("Item1", "0");
dt.Rows.Add("Item1", "1");
dt.Rows.Add("Item1", "2");
dt.Rows.Add("Item1", "3");
DataGridViewComboBoxColumn cmb = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
cmb.DefaultCellStyle.Font = new Font("Tahoma", 8, FontStyle.Bold);
cmb.DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = Color.BlueViolet;
cmb.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Flat;
cmb.Name = "ComboColumnSample";
cmb.HeaderText = "ComboColumnSample";
cmb.DisplayMember = "Item";
cmb.ValueMember = "Value";
DatagridView dvg=new DataGridView();
dvg.Columns.Add(cmb);
cmb.DataSource = dt;
for (int i = 0; i < dvg.Rows.Count; i++)
{
dvg.Rows[i].Cells["ComboColumnSample"].Value = (cmb.Items[0] as 
DataRowView).Row[1].ToString();
}
```

It worked with me very well